# IWorksheetFunction - problem with object reference

Tags: c#, .net

i use Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel

and i have error in my code with it

an object reference is required for the non-static field method or property

```
 public class CalculationsController : Controller
  {
 public double Irr(double a, double b)
    {

      Irr irr = new Irr()
      {
        a = a,
        b = b
      };

      var y = IWorksheetFunction.Irr(irr.a, irr.b); // here error

      return y;

    }

public class Irr
  {
    public double a { get; set; }
    public double b { get; set; }
  }
}
```

i cant do change in IWorksheetFunction.Irr, beacause its package

Comment: If the naming convention is applied correctly, then `IWorksheetFunction` is an interface. That means you need an instance of a class that implements said interface. You cannot make a static call (without an instance) to the interface.

Comment: By the way: `Irr` is a terrible name.

Comment: Sounds like you need to get the WorksheetFunction from your excel instance as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3955983/493566).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first problem with your code as highlighted by @Fildor in the comments. You can't make calls to an `Interface`. You should view `Interfaces` as blueprints. You should be calling the `WorksheetFunction` class instead since this implements the `IWorksheetFunction` `Interface`.

The second possible issue is that you haven't included the right library to access the `WorksheetFunction` class. You can include it by placing this at the very top of the file.

```
using Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel;
```

If this gives any issue you might need to install the `Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel` nuget package. [Here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/quickstart/install-and-use-a-package-in-visual-studio) is how you can do that